# Magento Remove Logout Link from Observer

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I was trying to remove a logout link from the Observer.
When I remove all top links, it is working. But not the logout link alone.
To Remove Top links I used this code

```
public function addHandle($observer)
```

{

```
  $layout = $observer->getLayout();           

  $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<reference name="top.links" />');
     $layout->generateXml();
```

}

To remove logout links
   This is not working

public function addHandle($observer)
   {

```
  $layout = $observer->getLayout(); 

  $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate(' <customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
    </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>
    ');

     $layout->generateXml();
```

}

Comment: try this 

<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
    </reference>

Comment: @faizanbeg nope not working

Comment: why are you trying to do this before generate xml? why not accessing the block after creation and before rendering to remove the link? another idea would be to copy over the customer.xml layout file and prevent the adding of the link at all by removing the part from the xml